# Run only one unit test from a test suite in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

Using `phpunit` command Laravel will run all unit tests in our project.
How to run one or specific Unit Tests in `Laravel 5.1`?

I just want to run `testFindToken` from my test suite.

```
<?php

use Mockery as m;
use App\Models\AccessToken;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class AccessTokenRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->accessToken = factory(AccessToken::class);
        $this->repo_AccessToken = app()->make('App\Repositories\AccessTokenRepository');
    }

    public function testFindToken()
    {
        $model = $this->accessToken->make();
        $model->save();
        $model_accessToken = $this->repo_AccessToken->findToken($model->id);
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class, $model);
        $this->assertNotNull(true, $model_accessToken);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use this command to run a specific test from your test suite.

```
phpunit --filter {TestMethodName}
```

If you want to be more specific about your file then pass the file path as a second argument

```
phpunit --filter {TestMethodName} {FilePath}
```

Example:

```
phpunit --filter testExample path/to/filename.php
```

**Note:**

If you have a function named `testSave` and another function named `testSaveAndDrop` and you pass `testSave` to the `--filter` 
like so

```
phpunit --filter testSave
```

it will also run `testSaveAndDrop` and any other function that starts with `testSave*`

it is basically a sub-string match. If you want to exclude all other methods then use `$` end of string token like so

```
phpunit --filter '/testSave$/'
```

Comment: Well explained. But for laravel if phpunit command is not configured with your project you will have to use `./vendor/bin/phpunit` instead.

Answer (score 18):

```
php artisan test --filter UserTest
```

Answer (score 15):

You should run `./vendor/bin/phpunit --help` to get all options with phpunit. And you can run phpunit with some option below to run specific method or class.

```
--filter <pattern>          Filter which tests to run.

--testsuite <name,...>      Filter which testsuite to run
```

Answer (score 3):

For windows environment this works for me:

in console:

```
vendor\bin\phpunit --filter login_return_200_if_credentials_are_fine tests/Unit/Http/Controllers/AuthControllerTest.php
```

WHERE

login_return_200_if_credentials_are_fine - your test method
tests/Unit/Http/Controllers/AuthControllerTest.php - path where test method defined

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but it might help someone.

To test specific test file

> php artisan test --filter AccessTokenRepositoryTest

To test specific case of that file

> php artisan test --filter AccessTokenRepositoryTest::testFindToken